# How do I make Flask in PyDev as a new project type?

Tags: eclipse, flask, pydev, liclipse

How can I make Flask an available project type in Eclipse (LiClipse actually) and PyDev?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about Flask in LiClipse/PyDev... just create a regular PyDev project and code your flask app in there ;)